# Webform error for event registration - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

I am getting this error at the top of a webform (in the civi section):

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in wf_crm_admin_form->buildParticipantTab() (line 930 of /home/site1/public_html/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/wf_crm_admin_form.inc).

It happens when a contact is added to an event. I have attached a screen capture.

A new part in the form has appeared. No idea where from. I think this might be causing the issue. See attached for for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be a problem with Custom Data (civicrm/admin/custom/group). A Set of Custom Fields had been created for participants without any fields added. I removed the group and problem is fixed.

Comment: Ok phew! Glad to see you solved this.

Comment: The answer was so very helpful to me. Thanks for reporting how you resolved it!